# three.js how to draw line with mousedown event

Tags: javascript, three.js, click

I have try a lot of ways to complete this effect,i want to draw a line of mouse down event,and i have seen many other questions but do not have any idea about it,so far i use the Ray caster method of intersectObjects() and get the position of the click,but i do not how to then,Hope someone give me advice,thanks very much.
Here are part of mine code:

```
event.preventDefault();
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = -( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;  
var raycaster=new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects,true);
console.log(intersects[0].point);//type of intersects[0] is object,one of attribute is point?
```

yesterday i write some codes and have complete part of my effect. Here are some code:

```
 var clickCount = 0;//initial value
 clickCount = clickCount+1;
 if(intersects.length>0)
 {
     switch(clickCount)
     {
         case 1:
                var startPoint=intersects[0].point;//store the first intersect point when the first click
                break;
    case 2:
                var endPoint =intersects[0].point;//store the second intersect point when the second click
                break;
     }
  }


clickCount=1;
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff,linewidth:2});
geometry.vertices.push(startPoint);
geometry.vertices.push(endPoint);
line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
scene.add(line);
```

but this is not the final effect what i wanted.this segment lines are all rays set up from the vector(0,0,0). here is the screenshot: 
[image: the red line are what i want and the white lines are real]

the red line is the effect what i want to implementate. Could anyone figure out the reason?thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to remember the first clicked object, then on the next click you will check, if it's the same object or another one, and if it's another one, then draw a line between them.

```
var intersected, lineObjects = [],
objects = [];
. . .
```

and in the event handler:

```
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    var found = intersects[0].object;
    if (found != intersected) {
      if (lineObjects.length > 0) {
        var line = lineObj(lineObjects[0].position, found.position);
        scene.add(line);
        lineObjects[0].material.color.setHex(lineObjects[0].userData.oldColor);
        intersected = null;
        lineObjects = [];
      } else {
        found.userData.oldColor = found.material.color.getHex();
        found.material.color.set(0x00FF00);
        intersected = found;
        lineObjects.push(found);
      }
    } else {
      found.material.color.setHex(found.userData.oldColor);
      intersected = null;
      lineObjects = [];
    }
  }
```

I've made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/xu2n6yhu/) example. Look at `onMouseDown()` function. All the things I described above are there.

Comment: This moment i am very grateful what you had done for me.i have puzzled with this problem a great deal of days.thank you very much.